# while i try to run react native in android emulator. I get Error type 3. Error: Activity class {com.eg/com.eg.MainActivity} does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-saga

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 10s

154 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 152 up-to-date

info Connecting to the development server...

info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.baqala/.MainActivity }

Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.baqala/com.baqala.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

Comment: Reopen on the device, it should be fine. Does your app name match your android code folder structure?

Comment: i reopen the device more than 3 time but its seems not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be getting this error if you are using product flavours or variants with `applicationIdSuffix "<YOUR SUFFIX>"`

My project has multiple build types and product flavours where each flavour specifies applicationIdSuffix in app/build.gradle. When you run `react-native run-android --variant=<VARIANT>` it will build but fail to open on the emulator. A solution is to add `--appIdSuffix '<YOUR SUFFIX>'` to your run command

For example:

```
react-native run-android --variant=stagingDebug --appIdSuffix 'staging'
```

React Native CLI will hopefully fix this in the future.